# How to read and process multiple files from s3 faster in python?

Tags: python, bash, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have multiple files in a particular folder location in s3. I want to read all of them. Currently, I loop all the files and create a dataframe using pandas read_csv and then concatenate all these files. But the process takes lot of time. I want something that can read the files and process them.

current code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
bg = s3.Bucket("bucket")
objects = bg.objects.filter(Prefix="prefix")
file_list = []
for obj in objects:
    df = pd.read_csv(f's3://bucket/{obj.key}')
    file_list.append(df)
final_df = pd.concat(file_list)
```

There are large number of files which I need to process.

Comment: Read the files from s3 in parallel into different dataframes, then concat the dataframes

Comment: You're seemingly going to process the data on a single machine, in RAM anyways - so i'd suggest preparing your data outside python. Do what it takes to max out your link speed (parallel download?), then use `cat` to concatenate your data (you can combine this with lz4 compression), only then load the final data to Pandas.

Comment: Perhaps Athene can do what you want. When the files are structured, Athene can look for data using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this:

1. Simple Method: Create a hive external table on the s3 location and do what ever processing you want in the hive.
   Eg: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MovieDetails (
   movieId int,
   title string
   )
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
   STORED AS TEXTFILE
   LOCATION 's3://us-east-1.****.samples/sparksql/movielens/movie-details';
2. Using Spark: Read the files using spark and you can create the same data frame and process them.
3. If the Files are coming in a streaming manner you can use Nifi with integration with SNS & SQS ( not applicable in this case )

Comment: Please, the OP has several simple csv files on a remote machine. The best answer sure does not involve 5 more 'advanced' technologies (especially those which are 'not applicable'). Maxing out network throughput first and concatenating data in the most effective manner is the key even with those fancy names..